# numpy savetxt sort order

Tags: sorting, numpy, save

I am trying to save text using numpy, I need to figure out how to sort before saving essentially I want a reverse order

`p` is array

```
3 2.5
2 1.98
1 7.2

with open('fin.dat', 'a') as fout:
    numpy.savetxt(fout,p,fmt='%.4f')
```

I want to save as

```
1 7.2
2 1.98
3 2.5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is p a 1 dimensional array? i.e. `p = np.ndarray([3, 2.5, 2, 1.98, 1, 7.2])`?

Comment: You don't need the whole `with open` shenanigans, you can pass the filename directly to savetxt `;)`

Comment: But it's good to know that you can put the `savetxt` in a `with open` block.  Though it may more useful with `loadtxt`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

p = np.array([3,2.5,2,1.98,1,7.2])
p = p[::-1]

>> [7.2,1,1.98,2,2.5,3]

np.savetxt(file,p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question to clarify that `p` is a 2d array.  You need to reverse `p` before giving it to `savetxt`.  For example

```
q = p[::-1,:]
```

reverses the order of the rows.

There is simple function that does this same thing:

```
q = np.flipud(p)
```